# What do the colours mean in the TortoiseGit log window?

Tags: version-control, tortoisegit

What do the red and flesh coloured bars represent?

[image]

Comment: It is worth adding though that these colours can be customized in **TortoiseGit > Settings > Colors**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are talking about the log dialog:

- the red are the <del>local</del> current branches
- the flesh ones are the remote branches
- the green ones are for <del>tags</del> non-current local branches
- the yellow ones are for tags

[Oran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71262/oran)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10938014/6309) (upvoted) has the complete list of color codes.

[image: log dialog]

Comment: @SurfRat: green, I guess, are for tags.

Comment: Actually red is the current branch.  Green are the local branches.  Tags are yellow.

Answer (score 33):

From the TortoiseGit source for [Colors.cpp](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/blob/master/src/TortoiseProc/Colors.cpp):

- CurrentBranch: Red
- LocalBranch: Green
- RemoteBranch: Peach
- Tag: Yellow
- Stash: Gray

The colors of the branch lines on the left aren't significant and don't correspond to the branch bar colors:

- BranchLine1: Black
- BranchLine2: Red
- BranchLine3: Green
- BranchLine4: Blue
- BranchLine5: Gray
- BranchLine6: Olive
- BranchLine7: Teal
- BranchLine8: Purple

Comment: Interesting. +1. I have included the red, peach and green ones in my answer, and linked to yours for the other colors.

Comment: How can I get branch name by its color?!

Comment: Now if *only* this would have been properly *documented* somewhere, so that we wouldn't have to dig through the source code!

Answer (score 1):

New marker: bisect

bisect good: blue

bisect bad: red (lighter)

Answer (score 0):

The question and answers are for a very old version of TortoiseGit.

Never version (>= 2.0) do not only have different colors, but also different shapes for indicating local branches, remote branches, remote tracking branches, stash, bisect refs, etc. (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61266764/3906760).

The current default colors are:

- CurrentBranch: Dark Red (two different shapes)
- LocalBranch: Green (two different shapes)
- RemoteBranch: Peach (two different shapes)
- Tag: Yellow (two different shapes)
- Stash: Gray
- Bisect Bad: Light Red
- Bisect Good: Blue
- Bisect Skip: Grey

The color of the commit graph does not correspondent to the colors of the shapes. THe line color is just there to make the graph better readable.

Some of the colors are configurable: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-colours2