# What do the different shapes of the labels in TortoiseGit Log window mean?

Tags: tortoisegit

Some labels are rectangular, whereas some labels have the corners cut.

**What do these different shapes mean?**

Example of remote branches:

[image: Various shapes of the labels]

Example of local branches:

[image: Local branches]

Example of tags:

[image: Tags]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

== Branches ==

The active branch is displayed in dark red (by default). The green ones are local branches and the peach ones are remote branches. Normally branches are displayed as normal rectangles.

The boxes with rounded corners for local branches indicate that it has an associated remote tracking (e.g., `master` and `deploy-pr-label`). The boxes with rounded corners for local remote branches are used to inducate which of (possible several remote branches) is the remote tracking branch (e.g., `master` and `origin/master` in the question).

== Tags ==

Tags are by default yellow. In Git there are two tag types: normal tags and annotated tags. The annotated ones have an apex at the right side.

[image: Tags]

== Special cases ==

The `stash` has a dark grey rectangle.

There are also reactangles to indicate the `bad` versions (light red) on bisecting, blue for known `good` and grey for `skip`.

== General ==

The colors can be changed in TortoiseGit settings: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-colours2

The color of the lines does not correspondent to the shape's colors.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. Where do you know this from? I tried hard to find the official documentation on this subject but failed.

Comment: I'm the project leader ;) I'm also adding this to the official documentation.